# Duplicate Post Data Struts

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, struts, jmeter

I try to test my save function by submit form using JMetter (submitting 100 data). In my function, first i save the data to database. But because there are so many data that saved duplicated, i try just to write the data. And I get the cause, the duplicate data come when i catch the data that submitted by JMetter. I want to ask, why submitted data is duplicate, whereas when i check the submitted the request (post) data using wireshark there is no duplicate that send by JMetter. That mean the problem is in struts. How to solve this, thank you.

Function code in action class to show the form

```
public String renderAddMaintenanceItemForm(){
    maintenanceItem = new MaintenanceItemDto();
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Jsp form code

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery("#frmAddMaintenanceItem").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            return postForm(form, "savemaintenanceitem", "listmaintenanceitem", true);
        }
    });
});
</script>

<h4 class="widgettitle nomargin shadowed">Add Maintenance Item</h4>
<div class="widgetcontent bordered shadowed nopadding">
<form id="frmAddMaintenanceItem" class="stdform stdform2">   
    <s:hidden name="maintenanceItem.id" value="%{maintenanceItem.id}"/> 
    <s:if test="maintenanceItem.criteria == 'perma'">
        <s:hidden name="maintenanceItem.criteria" value="%{maintenanceItem.criteria}"/> 
        <p>
            <label>Item Name</label>
            <span class="field">
                <s:textfield name="maintenanceItem.name" value="%{maintenanceItem.name}" cssClass='input-xlarge required chardigit' minlength="5" maxlength="50"/>
            </span>
            </p>
    </s:if>
    <s:else>    
            <p>
                <label>Tipe</label>
                <span class="field">
                    <select name="maintenanceItem.criteria" class="uniformselect required">
                        <option>Select</option>
                            <option value='event' <s:if test="maintenanceItem.criteria == 'event'">selected="selected"</s:if>>
                                Event
                            </option>
                            <option value='time' <s:if test="maintenanceItem.criteria == 'time'">selected="selected"</s:if>>
                                Time
                            </option>
                    </select>
                </span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Item Name</label>
                <span class="field">
                    <s:textfield name="maintenanceItem.name" value="%{maintenanceItem.name}" cssClass='input-xlarge required chardigit' minlength="5" maxlength="50"/>
                </span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Normal Treshold (KM)</label>
                <span class="field"><s:textfield name="maintenanceItem.normalTreshold" value="%{maintenanceItem.normalTreshold}" cssClass="input-xxlarge required"/></span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Max Treshold (KM)</label>
                <span class="field"><s:textfield name="maintenanceItem.maxTreshold" value="%{maintenanceItem.maxTreshold}" cssClass="input-xxlarge required"/></span>
            </p>
    </s:else>
    <p>
        <label>Note</label>
        <span class="field"><s:textfield name="maintenanceItem.note" value="%{maintenanceItem.note}" cssClass="input-xxlarge required"/></span>
    </p>
    <p class="stdformbutton">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit </button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn">Reset </button>
    </p>
</form>
</div>
```

and this the function to save user input (in this case, I just write it to console)

```
public String saveMaintenanceItem(){
    System.out.println(maintenanceItem.getName());
    /*messageDto = carService.saveMaintenanceItem(maintenanceItem);
    actionStatus = messageDto.getResult();
    SessionManager.serviceReturnToSession(session(), messageDto);*/
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

And when i check, it is like jmetter ignoring the javascript on the form. Jmetter directly post the data to action class. Is it right? And i still confuse why it still get duplicate data.

Comment: first of all show me what you have done and your code

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the javascript function called postForm, there is another form submission. That probably cause the double form submission. If you cannot find the problem cut the sections of the jsp page chunk by and check and submit to the action class.

Comment: but when i check, it is like jmetter ignoring the javascript on the form. Jmetter directly post the data to action class.

Comment: You can remove the div class from the html and test it again. The last time I encounter that problem is because of the scrollable div that I included in the jsp page. Make the request to the server with just one line of code for form submission and test it first, then add in more code until you get double submission.